# How to pass data in a promise chain, I am using sequelize

Tags: node.js

I am really struggling here. Admittedly I am no guru especially when it comes to node and asynchronous programming, I am an old C# .net developer so I am comfortable with code but struggling here.

Here's the back story, short and sweet. I have a pg database and I am using the sequelize ORM tools to create a relatively simple CRUD app.

Here's what I want to do.

1. Make a call to the findAll function on one object.
2. I need a piece of information from that first call so that I can make a subsequent call.

For instance. Lookup the current user to get their details, grab their ID and now lookup their display preferences.

I know I can run two requests that are not linked using Promise.all, here is an example of this already working.

```
var delConfig = deliverabiltyConfigs.findAll2(req.signedCookies.tsUser);
var delPack = deliverabilityPackages.findAll2();
Promise.all([delConfig, delPack]).then((results) =>{
    res.render('index', { title: 'Deliverability Calculator', UserEmail : req.signedCookies.tsUser, UserName : req.signedCookies.tsUserName, data:results[0], packs:results[1]});    
});
```

Where I am stuck is passing data from one promise to then next and needing them to run asynchronously.

Please help!

Comment: I assume your code sample has nothing to do with the question (i.e. it shows what you know how to do, but it does not show what you are *trying* to do)? Could you add a code sample for that as well?

Comment: That's part of the problem, I am not sure how to do what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way you can do this. Either use promise chaining or with `async & await`.

Promise chaining might be the simplest way to do this now, but I would suggest using async await as its easier to read. Since you didn't really provide a sample of what you were trying to do I will make something generic that should hopefully help.

So using promise chaining you would do something like:

```
pgConnection.findAll().then((data) => {
  const foo = data.foo;
  pgConnection.findSomething(foo).then((data2) => {
    console.log(data2);
  });
});
```

What is happening here is once the promise from `findAll()` is resolved successfully it will call the `.then` method and will pass the resulting data there for you to use in your next db query and then I am just printing out the result of the final db query.

This is how you could do it using async & await:

```
async function getFoo() {
  const data = await pgConnection.findAll();
  const foo = data.foo;
  const data2 = await pgConnection.findSomething(foo);
  console.log(data2);
}
```

The `await` keyword can only be used inside of an `async` function so it might not be as simple to change as just using a `.then` promise chain.

Comment: Thanks for the input and this is exactly what I thought it would look like however, it's not working for me. The console.log lines always log undefined and then the code fails because the variable that I am looking for from the previous step is undefined?

Comment: Ok in that case you can add some `.catch` statements to debug why the promise is not resolving. Or if you are using async/ await you can wrap it in a try-catch block. Here is a promise chain example:

```pgConnection.findAll().then((data) => {
  const foo = data.foo;
  pgConnection.findSomething(foo).then((data2) => {
    console.log(data2);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error in second promise: ' + err);
  });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error in first promise: ' + err);
  });```

Comment: Or just try make the first promise/ db call to work by printing out the result in a `.then` block and only once that is working move onto making the second db call inside that then block. Don't try to tackle all the problems at once ;)

Comment: OK now I am seeing this error -> Error in first promise: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Comment: That could be a number of things. Without seeing the code there isn't much I can do to help, I would first go and look at the documentation of the library you are using to make sure it does return a promise. At the moment it looks like the function you are calling is returning `undefined` and that is why you can't chain a `then` onto it.

Comment: If I try both of my operations on their own they work as expected. When I run the samples that you suggested in your initial response what I get is both console.logs return undefined. The code runs but does not do what's expected. I am using the sequelize library which I believe uses bluebird promises.

Comment: Here is my function async function test(req){
  const data = await deliverabilitySpecs.findAll2();
  const foo = data.dailyMaxPerIP;
  console.log(foo);
  let cfgObject = {
      "createdBy" :  req.body.createdBy,
      
    };     
  const data2 = await deliverabiltyConfigs.create2(cfgObject);
  console.log(data2);
}

Comment: Is `dailyMaxPerIP` actually defined? What is the result of `data`? Perhaps your response is not correct? If they work on their own then there shouldn't be any issues adding them together unless there is something wrong in another part of the code.